# Why does this code also take downregulated values instead of just upregulated values?

Tags: r, subset

```
DEG_data <- read.csv(file = 'DEG_changes(1).csv', header = TRUE)
concentrations <- DEG_data$concentration 
unique_concentration <- unique(DEG_data$concentration)
numDEGs <- DEG_data$numberDEGs
changeDEGs <- DEG_data$changeDEG


upregulated_indices <- which(changeDEGs == "upregulated")

upregulated_conc2nM <- numDEGs[upregulated_indices & concentrations == unique_concentration[1]]
upregulated_conc5nM <- numDEGs[upregulated_indices & concentrations == unique_concentration[2]]
upregulated_conc50nM <- numDEGs[upregulated_indices & concentrations == unique_concentration[3]]
```

I am trying to make a subset that contains just data from the "upregulated" part of the data column but it is also taking data from the column that is "downregulated"

Comment: Easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(DEG_data)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Also I suspect using `dplyr::filter` on the original data frame would greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @neilfws the data is quite long but I can provide a snippet of what the data set looks like 
`2997 50 nM upregulated 7566
2998 50 nM upregulated 7569
2999 50 nM upregulated 7809
3000 50 nM upregulated 7626
3001 2 nM downregulated -1539
3002 2 nM downregulated -1323
3003 2 nM downregulated -1343
3004 2 nM downregulated -1543
3005 2 nM downregulated -1301
3006 2 nM downregulated -1447
3007 2 nM downregulated -1555 `

Comment: A small representative dataset will do, edit the question to include it.

Comment: this is a bad representation but the upregulated and down are all in one column as well as the nM vals and other values